# Python Selenium で Chromeブラウザ「検証」モードで表示されているにも関わらず 要素が見つからない

Tags: python, selenium

スポーツクラブJEXERサイトに Selenium でログインを試みていますがログインできません。
ログインURLは以下となります。

○トップページ ⇒ ログインボタンを押下
https://www.jexer.jp/info/index.html

○ログインページ
https://jresports.e-atoms.jp/JEXERWebUser/Account/LogIn?ReturnUrl=%2fJEXERWebUser%2f

Chromeの「検証」や「ページのソースの表示」では、「ログインID」name="UserName"や
「パスワード」name="Password" の要素が HTMLで見えます。

しかしながら、Seleniumのプログラムを起動し、driver.page_source のHTMLを確認したところ、「ログインID」「パスワード」のHTML・タグが表示されません。

当初、iframe を疑い、iframe で別のフレームに移動し、HTMLを確認しましたが、全く別のページが表示されました。つまり、iframeが原因ではありませんでした。

Seleniumを使ってdriver.page_sourceを確認したところ、Webサイトにアクセスした際、JavaScriptなどで 全く別のページ（HTML）が表示されているように見えます。

その為、
・driver.find_element で Class名を指定して要素取得
・driver.find_element で XPATH名（フルパス）を指定して要素取得
しても、HTML内に要素が表示されていない為、取得できません。

このJEXERサイトのように、Chromeブラウザに表示されるHTMLと、Seleniumが取得したHTMLが全く異なる場合、どのような対処をすればよいか分からず、何日か悩んでおります。

どなたかよい対処方法のお知恵を拝借できないでしょうか。
宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

当該のリンクは以下の様になっています。`target="_blank"` が指定されていますので、ログイン画面は別ウィンドウ(タブ)に表示されます。

```html
<a href="https://jresports.e-atoms.jp/..." target="_blank">
    <img src="./images/btn_c.gif" alt="ログイン">
</a>
```

なので、`driver.switch_to.window()` でログイン画面に移動する必要があります。

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

url = 'https://www.jexer.jp/info/index.html'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
login_btn = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ul.btn > li > a')
login_btn.click()

time.sleep(3)

driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
print(driver.page_source)
```

Comment: なるほど！  別タブに移動していたのですね。気付けませんでした。
上記プログラムで 無事ログインできました。
大変助かりました。ありがとうございました。